# How to modify __getitems__ for a 2d array class (python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, multidimensional-array

Hi everyone I'm a beginner with python, I can't seem to get the functions **__getitem__** and **__setitem__** to work with a **2D array** within a custom class.

I've been trying implement a 2D array class for an OOP battleships project. I want to be able to change random elements on the grid using coordinate inputs.

```
class Grid:
    def __init__(self, width=10, height=10):
        self.grid = [["~" for i in range(0, width)] for i in range(0, height)]

    def __getitem__(self, point):
        return self.grid[x][y]

    def __setitem__(self, point, value):
        self.grid[x][y] = "value" 


def strike():
    p1 = Grid()

    x = int(input("x coord please"))
    y = int(input("y coord please"))
    p1[x][y] = "*"
```

When I call strike I get the following: **Exception has occurred: TypeError
cannot unpack non-iterable int object**

I know that both **__getitem__** and **__setitem__** take only one
argument and I could use a tuple and unpack 'point' like this right?

```
def __getitem__(self, point):
    x, y = point
    return self.grid[x][y]
```

But how could I actually implement that in my strike function?
Is this even right?

Comment: Note, you aren't working with a multidimensional array, you are working with list objects

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you want to achieve the ability for a `Grid` object to take a coordinate tuple as a subscript, what you propose is correct:

```
class Grid:
    def __init__(self, width=10, height=10):
        self.grid = [["~" for i in range(0, width)] for i in range(0, height)]

    def __getitem__(self, point):
        x, y = point
        return self.grid[x][y]

    def __setitem__(self, point, value):
        x, y = point
        self.grid[x][y] = value
```

so that:

```
grid = Grid()
grid[1, 2] = 3
print(grid[1, 2])
```

outputs:

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you implement `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to take tuple arguments, then you need to index with all the expected dimensions at once:

```
def strike():
    p1 = Grid()

    x = int(input("x coord please"))
    y = int(input("y coord please"))
    p1[x, y] = "*"                         # x, y is a 2-tuple
```

On the other hand, if you want to index each dimension separately, you need your methods in `Grid` to handle only one dimension at a time. So `__getitem__` would only index with `x` and return some kind of object representing a whole row, and that row object (whatever type it is) would be responsible for handling any further indexing (including both getting and setting of individual values).

For instance, you could return one of the inner lists you're using in `self.grid` now:

```
def __getitem__(self, row):
    return self.grid[row]        # returns a whole list of values
```

This specific implementation may be a bit perilous, as the external code could make changes that your class code won't expect (like changing the size of the row by appending or deleting values).

If you're only indexing one dimension at a time, you'd only need `__setitem__` in the `Grid` class if you wanted to be able to set a whole new row:

```
p1[x] = [v + 1 for v in p1[x]]  # this assumes whatever is representing a row is iterable
```

Assigning a single value won't call `Grid`'s `__setitem__` method, as `p1[x][y] = z` does a `__getitem__` call on `p1` (which is the `Grid`), then a `__setitem__` call on the row object (which the list or some other kind of row object returned by `Grid.__getitem__`).

Comment: Thanks for breaking this down.